# Maven turn off default goal execution

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, liquibase

I have next question:
  I use liquibase maven plugin and by default when i making mvn clean package it dropAll tables and updates them.

```
 <code>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
           <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.0.3</version>
              <configuration>
                 <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
               </configuration>
         </plugin>
</code>
```

But, i want to turn off execution of this plugin for all maven phases, i need it only when i am executing mvn liquibase:dropAll or mvn liquibase:update. How i can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always place the plugin inside a profile. So it won't run unless you activate the profile:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>liquibase</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

which you activate as follows:

```
mvn liquibase:update -Pliquibase
```